# How to open the remote file in vscode without vscode server?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I am using the vs code for most of my development, but often I am accessing the FreeBSD system or low-resource machine which cannot handle having vs code server.

is there any way to open a remote file, without vscode server?
only basic edit capability is enough.

Comment: Assuming you're on Linux, it should be possible to mount a remote filesystem and open a file on it as if it was local. I'm not sure how the mechanism is called, but on Xubuntu in Thunar it happens automatically when trying to access `ssh://1.2.3.4` as a directory.

Comment: I am looking for the same as you rahul. I need to develop on a remote host but cannot use VSCode server due to organizational factors. I don't know if there is another way to develop on a remote host without using the VScode server.